# List after columns: shall I use determiners?

Tags: determiners

In the following example, is the determiner optional or compulsory?

> X is defined by two parameters: scale and time shift.

or

> X is defined by two parameters: *the* scale and *the* time shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> X is defined by two parameters: scale and time shift.

is fine.
In a context that I imagine, I would consider *scale* and *time shift* labels. Unless you called the parameters *the scale* and *the time shift* elsewhere, you shouldn't use them in your example.

The second example sounds wrong at best. Some more context would be needed to support such a usage.